# Estilo para el div que contiene un button con estilo

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3, cakephp

Bueno el problema que tengo es que el submit queda muy abajo, como pueden ver en las fotos, y lo que quiero es que quede debajo del "Previous"

[image: Foto antes del click]

[image: Foto después del click]

Css

```
/*
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
*/
/* 
    Created on : 6/03/2018
    Author     : Andrés Tabares Vélez - Informatic Engineering Intern
    Celphone   : +57 302 333 7407
    E-mail     : andreytvelez@gmail.com
*/


a.tip {
    text-decoration: none
}

a.tip:hover {
    cursor: help;
    position: relative
}

a.tip span.by {
    display: none;
}

a.tip:hover span.by {
    /*border: #c0c0c0 1px dotted;*/
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 60px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 60px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 10px;
    /* margin: 10px; */
    width: 300px;
    /*height: 200px;*/
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.contenedor:hover .imagen {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.3);transform:scale(1.3);
    cursor:pointer; 
    cursor: hand;
}

.separator{
    padding: 0px 3% 0px 0px;
}

.contenedor {
    overflow:hidden; 
}

.navlist li
{
    align-content: center;
    display: inline;
}

#footer{ 
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 20;
    position:fixed;  
    bottom: 0;
    font-family: fantasy, verdana,arial;  
    font-size:10pt;   
    height: 73px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(50,171,224,1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(50,171,224,1) 0%, rgba(113,206,239,1) 29%, rgba(33,180,226,1) 41%, rgba(235,25,112,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(50,171,224,1)), color-stop(29%, rgba(113,206,239,1)), color-stop(41%, rgba(33,180,226,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(235,25,112,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(50,171,224,1) 0%, rgba(113,206,239,1) 29%, rgba(33,180,226,1) 41%, rgba(235,25,112,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(50,171,224,1) 0%, rgba(113,206,239,1) 29%, rgba(33,180,226,1) 41%, rgba(235,25,112,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(50,171,224,1) 0%, rgba(113,206,239,1) 29%, rgba(33,180,226,1) 41%, rgba(235,25,112,1) 100%);
}  

#content {
    background: grey;
    clear: both;
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px 120px 98px 20px;
}

#header, #header h1 a, #header h1{
    background-color:#84CCF4; 
}




/*basic reset*/
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  /*Image only BG fallback*/

  /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
  background: grey;
}

body {
  font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}
/*form styles*/
#msform {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;

  /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
  position: relative;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input,
#msform textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: montserrat;
  color: #2c3e50;
  font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
  width: 100px;
  background: #27ae60;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover,
#msform .action-button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27ae60;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
  counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #333;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 9px;
  z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  /*connector not needed before the first step*/
  content: none;
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
  background: #27ae60;
  color: white;
}


.aSubmit {
  -webkit-transition: color 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: color 0.5s;
  -o-transition: color 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: color 0.5s;
  transition: color 0.5s;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: 70%;
  font-weight: 100;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 200px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
.aSubmit.loading {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
.aSubmit.feedback {
  z-index: 1;
}
.aSubmit.feedback:after {
  -webkit-transition: background 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.2s, -moz-transform 0.2s;
  -o-transition: background 0.2s, -o-transform 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: background 0.2s, -ms-transform 0.2s;
  transition: background 0.2s, transform 0.2s;
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
.aSubmit:hover {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
svg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 240px;
  height: 220px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
rect {
  -webkit-transition: fill 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  -moz-transition: fill 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  -o-transition: fill 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  -ms-transition: fill 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  transition: fill 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  fill: #3e3f4c;
}
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke: #1ecd97;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
}
path#top,
path#bottom {
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke-dasharray 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  -moz-transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke-dasharray 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  -o-transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke-dasharray 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  -ms-transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke-dasharray 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke-dasharray 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  stroke-dasharray: 295px 1000px;
}
.loading-start .aSubmit {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
.loading-start .aSubmit.loading {
  color: #fff;
}
.loading-start .aSubmit.feedback:after {
  visibility: visible;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5, 2);
  -o-transform: scale(1.5, 2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5, 2);
  transform: scale(1.5, 2);
}
.loading-start #top,
.loading-start #bottom {
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke-dasharray 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25);
  -moz-transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke-dasharray 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25);
  -o-transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke-dasharray 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25);
  -ms-transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke-dasharray 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25);
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke-dasharray 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25);
  stroke-dasharray: 10px 1000px;
}
.loading-progress #top,
.loading-progress #bottom {
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s linear, stroke-dasharray 1s linear;
  -moz-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s linear, stroke-dasharray 1s linear;
  -o-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s linear, stroke-dasharray 1s linear;
  -ms-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s linear, stroke-dasharray 1s linear;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s linear, stroke-dasharray 1s linear;
  stroke-dasharray: 10px 1000px;
  stroke-dashoffset: -150px;
}
.loading-end .aSubmit.loading {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
.loading-end #top,
.loading-end #bottom {
  stroke: #f5f6f7;
}
.loading-end #top {
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke-dasharray 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  -moz-transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke-dasharray 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  -o-transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke-dasharray 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  -ms-transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke-dasharray 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke-dasharray 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  stroke-dasharray: 30px 1000px;
  stroke-dashoffset: -518px;
}
.loading-end #bottom {
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke-dasharray 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  -moz-transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke-dasharray 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  -o-transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke-dasharray 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  -ms-transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke-dasharray 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke-dasharray 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, -0.25, 0.75, 1.25), stroke 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  stroke-dasharray: 10px 1000px;
  stroke-dashoffset: -490px;
}
.loading-end rect {
  fill: #1ecd97 !important;
}
```

View

```
<!-- multistep form -->
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Cliente', array('class' => '', 'id' => 'msform'));
?>
<!-- progressbar -->
<ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Necesidad del cliente</li>
    <li>Informacion Personal</li>
    <li>finish</li>
</ul>
<!-- fieldsets -->
<fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Hablanos sobre tu necesidad</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Requerimiento</h3>



    <div class="DontGrowWidth">
        <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('informacion', array('placeholder' => 'Cuentanos sobre el problema que tienes', 'label' => false,
            'class' => 'validador txtInformacion'));
        ?>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn-nextOne" value="Next"  hidden/>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Hablanos sobre tu empresa</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Negocio</h3>
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->input('empresa', array('label' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Dinos el nombre de tu empresa',
        'class' => 'validador txtEmpresa'));
    echo $this->Form->input('telefono', array('label' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Dano el telefono de tu empresa',
        'class' => 'validador txtTelefono'));
    echo $this->Form->input('direccion', array('label' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Danos la direccion de tu empresa',
        'class' => 'validador txtDireccion'));
    ?>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn-nextTwo" value="Next" hidden/>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Hablanos sobre ti</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Cliente</h3>
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->input('cliente', array('label' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Dinos como te llamas',
        'class' => 'validador txtCliente'));

    echo $this->Form->input('horario', array('label' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Dinos en que horario podemos contactarte',
        'class' => 'validador txtHorario'));
    ?>

    <div id='captcha' class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfukUYUAAAAABRE_7Ap1RJOG8tpmUJOJNnFDeo1" data-callback='recaptcha_callback'></div>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />




    <div class="divSubmit" hidden>
        <a href="#" class="aSubmit">submit</a>
        <a class="aSubmit loading" href="#">loading</a>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 240 220">
        <rect id="middle" x="20" y="100" width="200" height="60" rx="30"></rect>
        <path id="top" d="
              M 60,100
              L 50,100
              C 33.4357078,100 20,113.427814 20,130
              L 20,130
              C 20,146.568541 33.4331197,160  50,160
              L190,160
              C206.570288,160 220,146.572314 220,130
              L220,100
              C220,-60 180, 80 160,100
              C140,120 100,160 100,160
              "></path>
        <path id="bottom" d="
              M180,160
              L190,160
              C206.564295,160 220,146.572186 220,130
              L220,130
              C220,113.431458 206.56688,100 190,100
              L 50,100
              C33.4297125,100 20,113.435296 20,130
              C20,130 20,120 20,140
              C20,220 180,200 120,140
              C100,120 80,100 80,100
              "></path>
        </svg>
        <a class="aSubmit feedback" href="#"></a>
    </div>

</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>



<!--echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden'));-->
```

Answer (score 0):

No es fácil encontrar el problema sin poder debugear con la consola, pero intenta jugar un poco con la clase en css que tienes en:

```
.aSubmit{
  top: 70%; // este valor intenta reducirlo y fijate si llegas a la posición deseada.
}
```

Saludos y suerte!

Comment: La cosa es que ese mueve solo el texto del boton, el boton como tal se mueve, ps para sincronizar el texto "submit" con el boton me toco editar ese. 
Como puedes ver en la vista aSubmit son las clases de los <a... que contienen "submit", "loading" y por ultimo el que se convierte en el chulo que se muestra en la segunda imagen

Comment: Entonces intenta agregar en Css estilos para el div que contiene tú botón de submit ".divSubmit". Intenta ponerle "position:relative"  y "top:-50px" y juega con el valor de ese top.

Answer (score 0):

En tu html después de la línea de código

```
<a class="aSubmit loading" href="#">loading</a>
```

tienes un **svg** que te esta generando un **height: 220px**. La solución  podía ser que dentro de tu tag **a** mandes a llamar tu imagen .svg, posteriormente  darle los estilos que desees, así eliminas el espacio que tienes.

```
<a href="#" class="aSubmit"> <img src="img/btn.svg" alt=""> </a>
```

Espero te sirva la respuesta.

Comment: Pero cual imagen? el svg es con fines decorativos para darle diseño al boton. 


`svg {
 position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 240px;
  height: 220px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}`

Comment: Con el svg puedes hacer un archivo .svg (archivo que tendría las mismas características de dar diseños a tu botón)y mandarlo llamar a dentro de tu ancla o colocarlo como fondo, así podrás manipular mejor los estilos y solucionar el problema de espacio que tienes. También lo que puedes hacer que tu class aSubmit tenga un top -50px, algos así.